# Facebook PopUp Login with Owin

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, owin

I'm using MVC with Owin external login with Facebook.

Owin doesn't open facebook login as popup.It redirects the page to facebook.

I know there is a option to make facebook login open as popup.We need to add the "&dialog=popup" in the URL.

I don't have this option with OWIN.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The popup is a JavaScript API feature. Since it needs to interact with JavaScript on page, it can't redirect you entirely to Facebook. However, with traditional OAuth, a redirect is how it works. So, no, you can't use a popup.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. After reading though the source, I found a solution:

Basically: you need to go ahead and create an authentication provider for Facebook. So create a class that inherits from FacebookAuthenticationProvider. Within this class, override the "ApplyRedirect" method. Make it look something like:

```
public override void ApplyRedirect(FacebookApplyRedirectContext context)
{
    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&display=popup");
}
```

Now simply wire this class up with your configuration, like so:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new **<the name of the class that you created>**()
    // the rest of your configuration such as app ID and secret
});
```

And that should be it!

Comment: will you please provide the full sample code link. thanks