# Passing display=touch to Facebook OAuth with Microsoft OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 app which I have configured for Facebook OAuth 2 login using the ASP.NET OWIN authentication model that ships with this version of MVC.

I want to tell Facebook to optimize its login page for touch-based devices. Facebook documentation says I should be able to do this by adding a display=touch parameter to the query string we pass to Facebook when we kick off the OAuth flow. (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)

This ought to be a simple thing to do, but I am at a total loss about how to go about customizing the various OWIN middleware classes to add this parameter.

How do I customize the OWIN auth flow to modify the Facebook OAuth URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook PopUp Login with Owin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646055/facebook-popup-login-with-owin)

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. will post details below

Comment: Let us know how you go, I couldn't get the touch dialog working on a desktop only on mobile...

Comment: I tried touch first and it made no difference in the emulator. Didn't actually try on a real device. Then went for popup which gave me a mobile friendly display on emulator & same on device, so have stuck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically: you need to go ahead and create an authentication provider for Facebook. So create a class that inherits from FacebookAuthenticationProvider. Within this class, override the "ApplyRedirect" method. Make it look something like:

```
public override void ApplyRedirect(FacebookApplyRedirectContext context)
{
    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&display=popup");
}
Now simply wire this class up with your configuration, like so:

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new **<the name of the class that you created>**()
    // the rest of your configuration such as app ID and secret
});
```

And that should be it!

Answer courtesy of @nlaq here: [Facebook PopUp Login with Owin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646055/facebook-popup-login-with-owin)